# Session lost too fast for 2 apps on the same IIS server , ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, iis-7, session-cookies

I have a situation where I have 2 applications on my IIS that are running on the same domain.
each on it own directory.

example :

1) www.a.com/dir1 - APP1

2) www.a.com/dir2 - APP2

Both apps are running in inProc mode.

I do not use any load balance.

what happens is that APP2 (APP1 is working fine) keeps losing session after 7 - 10 min regardless of all the settings I have input.

Things I have tired:

1) Changing the cookie name of APP2 so that each app will have a unique session cookie name.

2) I have set the timeout window to 240 min.

3) I have placed log on the application start and end event and also on the session start and end and did not find any anomalies, (I see session end events invoked and application end invoked)

4) I have made sure no anti virus is scanning my web.config file.

5) I have moved APP1 to a different application pool.

Your ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your session is running "InProc" mode? If yes then you might need to configure your Apps to use State Server or Database Mode of session.

Comment: Yes all of my applications are inProc mode. Why will I have to do that ? I do not need them to share ASP.NET session...

Comment: Hmm. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx. "In-process mode simply means using ASP.NET session state in a similar manner to classic ASP session state. That is, session state is managed in process and if the process is re-cycled, state is lost. Given the new settings that ASP.NET provides, you might wonder why you would ever use this mode. The reasoning is quite simple: performance." from the same link..

Comment: that implies that the session is recycled, and I have not recycled my session at any point in my code, so I would like to know why is my inProc session gets recycled? Could it be that that the 2 apss are sharing the same process worker???? although they reside in different application pools?

Comment: The worker process can recycle itself at any time.  You don't have to explicitly do it.  For example, if App1 is an app that displays content from a CMS, and App 2 is creating huge reports that fit into App1, it is highly likely App2 would recycle when App1 wouldn't.

Comment: So this could happen if I am short in memory and the IIS needs to clean up. Well both my Apps are not generating big reports nor are they using exceptional amount of memory, also my server has lots of free memory on production environment...

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. Have you tried keeping both apps in separate worker processes (Application Pools)?

Comment: Yes both applications are in different application pools on the IIS.

Comment: Is your website load-balanced? If it is, InProc will not work and you'll need a State Server or SQL Session State.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, the things that you've tried are good checks.  Are you sure there isn't any Session.Clear() somewhere?

Does APP2 still lose session if APP1 is not running?
How big in memory does the worker process get?  Although, if it resets, I think you'd see something in Session start and end.

Comment: I do not use Session.Clear(). Both APPS are running together, APP2 cannot run without APP1 so I cannot test that...